# Create password-protected zip file

Tags: vbscript, winzip

I have to zip all the files in a folder and make it password protected.

I googled and found one solution which uses the inbuilt functionality of Windows. The code goes like below:

```
folder1 = "F:\WLMS_TEAM\TOUHID\Script"
zipfile = "F:\WLMS_TEAM\TOUHID\MyTmp.zip"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.OpenTextFile(zipfile, 8, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) _
  & String(18, Chr(0))

Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set zip = ShellApp.NameSpace(zipfile)
zip.CopyHere folder1
WScript.Sleep 2000
```

Can I make it password protected?

Or if you can help with some other code to use WinZip (not any other tool) to achieve the same.

Or It would be ok to have a separate code to password protect a pre-generated zip file.

Comment: Since you have chosen to do it only with winzip, i can't reply to you, because i know a solution but in winrar ,so i respect your choice and if you change your mind just tell me

Comment: Sorry, :( We have only winzip full version installed on our server. I have to go ahead with WinZip only. Unfortunately the solution provided by Ansgar is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can run WinZip on the command-line like this:

```
winzip32.exe -a -s"Password" "C:\path\to\your.zip" *.*
```

Wrapped in VBScript:

```vb
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "winzip32.exe -a -s""Password"" ""C:\path\to\your.zip"" *.*", 0, True
```

I don't think the `Shell.Application` object allows the creation of password-protected zip files.

Comment: I have winzip64 installed. When I run your code:

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sh.Run "C:\Program Files\WinZip\WINZIP64.EXE -a -sPassword F:\WLMS_TEAM\TOUHID\MyPwdTmp.zip *.*", 0, True

I get "The system cannot find the specified file" error.
Any issues?

Comment: My code looks for files in the current directory. Check that the current directory is what you think it is. Also check that the directory `F:\WLMS_TEAM\TOUHID` exists. And make sure that the WinZip executable is either in the `%PATH%` or called with its full path.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I think -pPassword used for Winrar and you should use -sPassword for Winzip ! see this Doc ==> http://www.memecode.com/docs/winzip.html

Comment: @Hackoo I actually meant to write `-s`. No idea how that turned into `-p` between my brain and my fingers. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of searching, trial and error, I got this working like below:
I hope somebody who comes out looking for the similar problems might find it useful.

```
strWinZipDir = "C:\Program Files\WinZip\WINZIP64.exe"
strZipFileToCreate = LocalPath & "FileName.zip"
strFilesToZip  = LocalPath & "*.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strWinZip = objFSO.GetFile(strWinZipDir).ShortPath
strCommand = strWinzip & " -min -a -s""Password"" -r """ & strZipFileToCreate & """ " & strFilesToZip

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExec = objShell.Exec(strCommand)

Do While objExec.Status = 0
 Wscript.Sleep(200)
Loop

Set objShell = Nothing
Set objExec = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```